# Apache redirecting to wrong port (how to replace str in varnish)

Tags: redirect, apache2, varnish

I have a server configured with varnish on port 80 -> apache2 on port 81

if i go to a folder without a trailing slash ( `http://xxx/test` ) it tries to redirect to ( `http://xxx:81/test/` )

is it possible to stop apache from doing that ? it breaks every single thing from phpmyadmin to svn....

maybe a rule in varnish to drop the :81 from the redirect ? but im not good in configuring advanced varnish..

Answer (score 0):

```
sub vcl_deliver {

    if(resp.http.Location){
        set resp.http.Location = regsub(resp.http.Location, ":81/","/");
    }
}
```

(eventually check if the request host matches the response Location: host )